# AWS - charged for regional data transfer - in/out/between EC2 AZs or using elastic IPs or ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I'm using AWS and today I was charged for "regional data transfer - in/out/between EC2 AZs or using elastic IPs or ELB".

I have

- 1 ELB (on 2 different AZs)
- 1 EC2 (on a single AZ)
- 1 RDS

(one API call to the ELB is routed to the EC2 that it's calling the mysql DB on RDS)
They are all in the same region (frankfurt). I read this: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=326076 and this: https://serverfault.com/questions/198459/amazon-aws-regional-data-transfer-in-out-between-ec2-avail-zones but I still don't understand why I was charged.

Is it normal to be charged for the data transfer between ELB and EC2? Or am I doing something wrong? Since the data is transferred inside the same region throught internal IPs I believe I should not be charged.

EDIT: is it possible that I'm charged for the traffic from ELB on AZ_2 to the EC2 on AZ_1 (AZ_1 and AZ_2 are two different AZ)?

Thanks for your support.

Comment: Are you using more than one AZ for your EC2 instances? Are you using more than one AZ for your ELB? How much are you charged?

Comment: One only EC2, so for EC2 I'm using a single AZ. But the ELB is on two different AZ. I was charged 0.03€ for 3Gb of traffic.

Comment: The data transfer may be the ELB-to-EC2 for 2 different AZs. Try eliminating the extra ELB so that the ELB and EC2 are in the same AZ only.

Comment: I did but I'm still charged "$0.010 per GB - regional data transfer - in/out/between EC2 AZs or using elastic IPs or ELB"

Comment: Contact AWS support. They are the only one that can give you a concrete answer.

Comment: what zone is the RDS instance on?